# How to implement remove-key to completely undo the effect of define-key

Tags: key-bindings

A long time ago I implemented `remove-key` to completely undo the effect of `define-key`, but when I just tried that implementation, it did not work reliably. How would you implement `remove-key` so that for any given key this is true:

```el
(let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
  (define-key map KEY 'bound)
  (remove-key map KEY)
  map)
=> (keymap)
```

It should also work for non-sparse keymaps. And when a sub-keymap is involved which becomes empty when the key is removed, then the sub-keymap should also be removed.

Here's the documentation - now I only need an implementation :-)

```lisp
(defun remove-key (keymap key)
  "In KEYMAP, remove key sequence KEY.
Make the event KEY truely undefined in KEYMAP by removing the
respective element of KEYMAP (or a sub-keymap) as opposed to
merely setting it's binding to nil.

There are several ways in which a key can be \"undefined\":

   (keymap (65 . undefined) ; A
           (66))            ; B

As far as key lookup is concerned A isn't undefined at all, it is
bound to the command `undefined' (which doesn't do anything but
make some noise).  This can be used to override lower-precedence
keymaps.

B's binding is nil which doesn't constitute a definition but does
take precedence over a default binding or a binding in the parent
keymap.  On the other hand, a binding of nil does _not_ override
lower-precedence keymaps; thus, if the local map gives a binding
of nil, Emacs uses the binding from the global map.

All other events are truly undefined in KEYMAP.

Note that in a full keymap all characters without modifiers are
always bound to something, the closest these events can get to
being undefined is being bound to nil like B above."
  ...)
```

Why do I want that? It has already been mentioned in the above doc-string, but here it is again, quoting [(elisp)Format of Keymaps](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Format-of-Keymaps.html) (emphasis mine).

> **When the binding is `nil`**, it doesn't constitute a definition but **it
>   does take precedence over a default binding or a binding in the parent
>   keymap**.  On the other hand, a binding of `nil` does *not* override
>   lower-precedence keymaps; thus, if the local map gives a binding of
>   `nil`, Emacs uses the binding from the global map.

`(define-key map KEY nil)` does not remove the entry for `KEY`, it just sets the binding to `nil`, which "doesn't constitute a definition", but which never-the-less can have an effect.

Comment: A general implementation that does what you want in all possible cases is a fair bit of work.  So I think you should give a bit more detail about the particular situation where you need it: the fact that this operation doesn't exist yet is a good hint that it's rarely needed.

Comment: @Stefan: it's probably rarely needed because default key bindings are rarely used (I guess the question arose from a magit related situation since tarsius is magit's maintainer, and magit does use default key bindings).

Comment: @npostavs No this has nothing to do with Magit. I would just like to edit existing keymaps in a semi-automated way following a set of rules of the form "if X is bound to a command then instead bind Y to that command and unbind X". It's more complicated than that, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: @Stefan "you should give a bit more detail about the particular situation where you need it". Yes, I will ask a separate question for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually I came up with a solution that satisfies me and added it to my [`keymap-utils` package](https://github.com/tarsius/keymap-utils).

```el
(defun kmu-remove-key (keymap key)
  "In KEYMAP, remove key sequence KEY.
Make the event KEY truely undefined in KEYMAP by removing the
respective element of KEYMAP (or a sub-keymap) as opposed to
merely setting its binding to nil.

There are several ways in which a key can be \"undefined\":

   (keymap (65 . undefined) ; A
           (66))            ; B

As far as key lookup is concerned A isn't undefined at all, it is
bound to the command `undefined' (which doesn't do anything but
make some noise).  This can be used to override lower-precedence
keymaps.

B's binding is nil which doesn't constitute a definition but does
take precedence over a default binding or a binding in the parent
keymap.  On the other hand, a binding of nil does _not_ override
lower-precedence keymaps; thus, if the local map gives a binding
of nil, Emacs uses the binding from the global map.

All other events are truly undefined in KEYMAP.

Note that in a full keymap all characters without modifiers are
always bound to something, the closest these events can get to
being undefined is being bound to nil like B above."
  (when (stringp key)
    (setq key (kmu-parse-key-description key t)))
  (define-key keymap key nil)
  (setq key (cl-mapcan (lambda (k)
                         (if (and (integerp k)
                                  (/= (logand k ?\M-\0) 0))
                             (list ?\e (- k ?\M-\0))
                           (list k)))
                       key))
  (if (= (length key) 1)
      (delete key keymap)
    (let* ((prefix (vconcat (butlast key)))
           (submap (lookup-key keymap prefix)))
      (when (and (not (eq submap 'ESC-prefix))
                 (= (length submap) 1))
        (delete (last key) submap)
        (kmu-remove-key keymap prefix)))))
```

---

*The old answer because it discusses some details:*

After looking at it again I realized that my existing implementation actually works quite well, but is very picky about the format of the KEY. It has to be a vector in the "internal format", so `[?\C-i]` would work but `[(control ?i)]` would not. All elements have to be either integers or symbols.

```el
(defun remove-key (keymap key)
  (define-key keymap key nil)
  (setq key (cl-mapcan (lambda (k)
                         (if (and (integerp k)
                                  (/= (logand k ?\M-\^@) 0))
                             (list ?\e (- k ?\M-\^@))
                           (list k)))
                       key))
  (if (= (length key) 1)
      (delete key keymap)
    (let* ((prefix (vconcat (butlast key)))
           (submap (lookup-key keymap prefix)))
      (delete (last key) submap)
      (when (= (length submap) 1)
        (remove-key keymap prefix)))))
```

`?\M-\^@` is Emacs' value for the meta key.

To make this function less picky about the format of the KEY, this might work:

```el
(setq key (if (stringp key)
              (edmacro-parse-keys key t)
            (edmacro-parse-keys (key-description key) t)))
```

The first line `(define-key keymap key nil)` should take care of the case where KEY is part of the full keymap's char-table, assuming this is correct:

> Note that in a full keymap all characters without modifiers are
>   always bound to something, the closest these events can get to
>   being undefined is being bound to nil like B above.

That first line should also prevent the parent keymap from being modified, in the non-char-table case. I do not avoid doing that for a full keymap, because there is no `full-keymap-p` predicate. Usually the first element of a full keymap is the char-table, but last I checked that was not actually enforced, a keymap also functions as a full keymap if a later element is a char-table. It just seemed wiser to do some potentially unnecessary work instead of risking getting it wrong.

Comment: `?\M-\^@` (or just `?\M-\0`) gives Emacs' character value for the meta key, so the `cl-mapcan` is converting any `M-<x>` into `ESC <x>` (and also converting vector to list).

Comment: I've accepted my own answer so that the @Community bot can relax. But I am still open for other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with

```
(defun remove-key (keymap key)
  (let ((binding (assq key keymap))
        (parentbinding (assq key (keymap-parent keymap))))
    (and binding
         (not (eq binding parentbinding)) ;Don't change the parent!
         (delq binding keymap))))
```

This will only work for a sparse `keymap` and expects `key` to be a single key, rather than a key sequence.  [ And it's guaranteed 100% untested, so even for that limited case it might not work.  ]

Answer (score 2):

This is a simplified version of information extracted from the accepted answer posted by tarsius which contains more advanced information and requires a package for `kmu-parse-key-description`. This small stand alone function undoes the effect of `define-key` by removing the declaration from the keymap. Removing the declaration is more effective than setting its value to nil.

```el
(defun remove-key (keymap key)
  (define-key keymap key nil)
  (setq key (cl-mapcan (lambda (k)
                         (if (and (integerp k)
                                  (/= (logand k ?\M-\^@) 0))
                             (list ?\e (- k ?\M-\^@))
                           (list k)))
                       key))
  (if (= (length key) 1)
      (delete key keymap)
    (let* ((prefix (vconcat (butlast key)))
           (submap (lookup-key keymap prefix)))
      (delete (last key) submap)
      (when (= (length submap) 1)
        (remove-key keymap prefix)))))
```

Thanks to tarsius, the above code works.

I used `remove-key` to remove troublesome cua keys which, when set to `nil` using `define-key` caused <kbd>C-x</kbd> to behave unpredictably, if any reaction at all.

```el
(remove-key cua--prefix-repeat-keymap (kbd "C-x"))
(remove-key cua-global-keymap (kbd "<C-return>"))
```

The <kbd>C-x</kbd> declaration is successfully removed. Unfortunately, cua is somehow still affecting <kbd>C-return</kbd> is still a problem, but remove-key did remove the declaration as promised. Some interlinks can get complex. Using `remove-key` get rid of the declaration actually simplifies the situation.

Comment: This seems to be an (elaborate) comment on another answer - like a QA report on that answer. It doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to comment, or I would have in a much shorter manner and it would have been better.

Comment: Paul: Maybe just clarify that [kmu-parse-key-description](https://github.com/tarsius/keymap-utils/blob/master/keymap-utils.el#L258) is available in the package, but this function you have supplied works in a stand-alone fashion.

Comment: I understand that although you would have preferred to comment, you wrote an actual answer instead - so I'm removing the "not-an-answer" flag and leaving the answer as it is. If you wish to improve on this, you should make more clear how the post answers the question, but for now I'll take as given that this is an attempt to answer.